# Discord.py cooldown decorator not triggering

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a `discord.py` bot that has several commands that utilize the cooldown function in order to keep users from spamming them, or to keep from pinging APIs too quickly. I have not changed anything in the code, except for add a single command, which is the following (all you need to understand is that it sends a local image upon being called, and that there shouldn't be anything within it that would affect the cooldown system.):

```py
@commands.cooldown(rate=30, per=1, type=commands.BucketType.user)
@commands.command(name='imagereact', aliases=['ir'])
async def image_react(self, ctx, image=None, *, quote=''):
    if image == 'list':  # if user wants list of all available images.
        images = [img for x, y, img in os.walk('./images')][0]  # get all images in the ./images directory.
        images = [img[:img.find('.')] for img in images]  # remove the file extension from the name of each image.

        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Image reaction list",
            description="\n".join(images),
            colour=0xef8b4f
        )

        embed.description += f"\n\n**Run `{ctx.command} image` to check out an image!**"

        return await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    if not image:
        return await ctx.send(f"You must pass in an image to send, {ctx.author.mention}.")

    for roots, dirs, files in os.walk('./images'):
        # get all images in the ./images directory, to be used later
        for file in files:
            ind = file.find('.')  # to take off the file extension

            if image == file[:ind]:
                with open(f"images/{file}", 'rb') as img:
                    await ctx.channel.delete_messages([ctx.message])  # clean up the invoke message
                    return await ctx.send(content=quote, file=discord.File(img, image+file[ind:]))

    message = await ctx.send(f"Image `{image}` not found, {ctx.author.mention}.")
    asyncio.sleep(3)
    await ctx.channel.delete_messages([message])
```

Previous to adding this command, there have been zero issues with the cooldown system, and it would raise an error upon being abused, as desired. However, after running the code today, and adding this section, the cooldown doesn't seem to work anymore, for any command. I created a test command, seen here:

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.cooldown(rate=3000, per=2, type=commands.BucketType.user)
async def foo(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("bar")
```

which has a `rate` of 3000, just to test if there is an issue in whether or not it's ms or seconds. Still, I can call `foo` dozens of times in rapid succession, and no error is raised. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rate` is number of times a command can be used before triggering a cooldown.

`per` is amount of seconds to wait for a cooldown when it’s been triggered.

Docs: [`cooldown`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.cooldown)

You have mixed rate and per maybe and cooldown time is in seconds

`cooldown` decorator should be after `command` decorator

So you need **`@commands.cooldown(rate=1, per=30, type=commands.BucketType.user)`**